# Error running ionic in my device android, no such file apk

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I searched several posts here for my mistake but none could solve it. When i try to run my ionic app using `ionic cordova run android --device` show this error:

```
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess native-run.

        native-run.cmd android --app platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-d... exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

I tried: remove platform android, add platform, build and run again

I checked:
- **native-run android --sdk-info**

```
SDK Location:         C:\Users\codewise\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
AVD Home:             C:\Users\codewise\.android\avd

API Level:            29
Packages:             Android SDK Platform 29  platforms;android-29  3
                      Sources for Android 29  sources;android-29  1


API Level:            28
Packages:             Android SDK Platform 28  platforms;android-28  6
                      Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image  system-images;android-28;google_apis_playstore;x86  8


API Level:            26
Packages:             Android SDK Platform 26  platforms;android-26  2
                      Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image  system-images;android-26;google_apis_playstore;x86  7
                      Sources for Android 26  sources;android-26  1


Tools:

Android Emulator  emulator  29.2.1
Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2  build-tools;29.0.2  29.0.2
Android SDK Platform-Tools  platform-tools  29.0.4
Android SDK Tools  tools  26.1.1
SDK Patch Applier v4  patcher;v4  1
```

-**ionic cordova run android --list**

```
[native-run] Connected Devices:
[native-run]   samsung SM-A305GT (API 28) RQ8M90CGZWW
[native-run] Virtual Devices:
[native-run]   Pixel 2 API 28 (API 28)
```

And using **--verbose**

```
      Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: 'process.exit' received +0ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: running 3 functions +1ms
  ionic:utils-process error while killing process tree for 17988: { Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 17988 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERRO: o processo "17988" n�o foi encontrado.
  ionic:utils-process 
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 17988 /T /F' } +125ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: error from function: { Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 17988 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERRO: o processo "17988" n�o foi encontrado.
  ionic:utils-process 
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 17988 /T /F' } +338ms
  ionic:utils-process error while killing process tree for 17404: { Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 17404 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERRO: o processo "17404" n�o foi encontrado.
  ionic:utils-process 
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 17404 /T /F' } +5ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: error from function: { Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 17404 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERRO: o processo "17404" n�o foi encontrado.
  ionic:utils-process 
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 17404 /T /F' } +4ms
  ionic:utils-process error while killing process tree for 14920: { Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 14920 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERRO: o processo "14920" n�o foi encontrado.
  ionic:utils-process 
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:389:11)
  ionic:utils-process     at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
  ionic:utils-process     at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:606:12)
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 14920 /T /F' } +41ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: error from function: { Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 14920 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERRO: o processo "14920" n�o foi encontrado.
  ionic:utils-process 
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:389:11)
  ionic:utils-process     at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
  ionic:utils-process     at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:606:12)
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 14920 /T /F' } +8ms
  ionic:utils-process processExit: exiting (exit code: 1) +35ms
```

please does anyone know how to fix this?